# Animate raphael objects

Tags: javascript, html, path, raphael

I'm quite new to raphael.js and I'm trying to animate raphael elements. For example, I've drawn an arrow using paper.path().

```
var arrow = paper.path("M10,10L100,100");
arrow.attr({
    "stroke-width": 5,
    "stroke-dasharray": "-.",
    "arrow-end": "classic-wide-long"
});
```

How do I make the arrow's color seem like flashing when it's drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.animate()`.
E.g.,

```
arrow.animate({
    "25%": {stroke: "pink", easing: "bounce"},
    "50%": {stroke: "red", easing: "bounce"},
    "75%": {stroke: "pink", easing: "bounce"},
    "100%": {stroke: "red", easing: "bounce"}
},2500);
```

Where the percentages are the frame steps to reaching the specified duration (2500ms in this case).

Comment: Interesting, not seen that format before, looks very useful. Is it documented anywhere ?

Comment: I've only found an example here: [raphaeljs tutorial](http://cancerbero.mbarreneche.com/raphaeltut/#sec-types-gradient) under **Key Frame Animation**
I haven't seen full documentation.@Ian